# How to use commas with "so"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I was a slow runner, so they put me at first base.
I was a slow runner so, they put me at first base.
I was a slow runner ,so, they put me at first base.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

The first is correct if I'm not mistaken. You only add a comma if "so" is at the start of a sentence. For example, "So, how is the project coming along?" would be correct.

Comment: Of the three the first one is correct, however the comma is optional anyway. There's nothing wrong with "I was a slow runner so they put me at first base." There is a slight difference in emphasis with the comma. With it there is more of a sense of finality, without it I would probably expect more information about the game, perhaps "I was a slow runner so they put me on first base, but I managed to tag out their star player."

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.